# Add attachment in a List from a file in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, modern-experience, attachments

I have a SharePoint Site.

In Site Contents, I have a list named Test which have columns (Title and Attachment).

And in Documents directory, I have a pdf file named test.pdf.
I want to create new item (or edit exist item) in the list with the pdf file as attachments.

But if I click Add attachment button in edit / new, only local file picker is opened. Can I add the pdf file which is in Document library type as the attachment?

I already enabled "Attachments to list items" option in List settings / Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known behavior in SharePoint lists. SharePoint out of the box attachments column does not allow adding files from document library using SharePoint UI.

It only allows you to upload documents from your local computer system. Hence when you click on Add attachment button from SharePoint list form, it will show you the local computer file picker to upload the files.

Comment: I see. So I need to make steps separate to uploading files on Document Library and download it on my local machine, then attach on the list. Not directly connect from the document library to list item...

Comment: Are you going to attach multiple files or single file from library to list item? If single file, you can use hyperlink column in list and add link to document in that column against list item.